# Android Touch Event - Having an Up Down and Move Event

Tags: java, android, user-interface, touch-event

I have a problem with Touch Events which i am sure is possible.

Lets say i have a Cube when i Swipe the screen left or right i want the Cube to move the same and then when i do a quick touch (Down) i want the cube to rotate by a certain amount.

Currently if i swipe the screen then the Cube will move left or right as i want but it will also rotate once.

Here is my code.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if (event != null)
    {
        float x = event.getX();
        //float y = event.getY();

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            if (mRenderer != null)
            {
                float CubeX = (x - mPreviousX) / mDensity / 2f;  
                mRenderer.mCubeXMovement += CubeX;
            }
        }           
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            if (mRenderer != null)
            {
                float deltaX = 45f;
                mRenderer.mDeltaX += deltaX;
            }
        }

        mPreviousX = x;
        mPreviousY = y;

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

The above code only looks for the Down event which is why it rotates and moves on any type of touch
How could i implement this so that the cube will only rotate when a down and up event are sequential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's either DOWN [ -> MOVE ] -> UP or DOWN [ -> MOVE ] -> CANCEL

but ACTION_UP always follows ACTION_DOWN

to check for a quick touch, mark the down location (x&y) and then make sure that the UP location is within TOUCH_SLOP (ViewConfiguration.getScaledTouchSlop()) of the down location.

Comment: Ok But if i want to say rotate when i get a DOWN then UP and not just a DOWN, how do i do that? Thanks

Comment: in Move, wait until the X delta (moveX-downX) > touchSlop before you move the object.  
In Up, only rotate the object if the xDelta <= touchSlop.  
In Down, only mark the location, don't do anything becuase it's too early to know the users intentions

Comment: That makes sense mostly. A couple of questions though you can see from the code above that i rotate by 45 each time. The TOUCH_SLOP is 16 which means the it will never rotate

Comment: ACTION_DOWN and _UP refer to the finger touching and lifting from the surface, not the direction of motion on the surface.  touch_slop is about 1/3 of a finger's width.. so a motion in the x direction (deltaX > slop) means they want to move the object. No motion (deltaX < slop) just means the finger stayed in the same place.  You are always rotating by 45 degrees, so the slop is just telling you whether it's a touch in place or not

Comment: Thank you very much for your help i managed to get it working with your suggestions, the only thing i had to do differenlty was creating another pX value which was set to e.getX in the down and in the move was set to the previousX if deltaX > Slop. I hope that makes sense to anyone else